# Neos 2.1 (user management and multisite option)

Tags: neoscms

I have several customers under my Typo3 installation. Every user can edit his own site and has his own folder to upload his stuff. Is there a way in Neos to do the same?

Here my explanation:

1. Create Sitepackage for Customer
2. Create User for Customer
3. Create Uploadfolder for Customer
4. Customer can login an edit his site, but without seeing the other Sites or Files or other Packages which where uploaded by other Customer like the Multiplesites in Typo3.

I hope the explanation is good enough.

Comment: Go trough Neos documentation - http://neos.readthedocs.org/en/stable/CreatingASite/MultiSite.html#separating-assets-between-sites and  http://neos.readthedocs.org/en/stable/CreatingASite/Security.html I tried to achieve similar thing year ago and finished with separate instances for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

In Neos, everything get's uploaded in the Media Module. But you can generate collections and add this to a particular site. But every user will see the other pages. You have to make seperate instances for each customer. If you would do in one instance, you would have many drawbacks:

- Update Neos (You will have to!) would be a hassle
- You can't set content dimensions for a particular site, it is always for the whole instance.
- All packages would be available for every site. Not good.
- If you have trouble with one, you have trouble with all sites.

If you want to have a low-priced but not cheap hosting, who runs Neos, try http://uberspace.de. To get Neos on Uberspace running, you will have to set `phpBinaryPathAndFilename` in the Settings.yaml correctly.